# Start site from cmd

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I'm trying to start a ASP.NET MVC project on IIS Express from cmd using this command

`iisexpress /site:MySiteName`

but I get this message

> The following site was not found in the configuration file

What I'm missing here !?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line):

> /config:config-file  The full path to the applicationhost.config file.
>   **The default value** is the IISExpress8\config\applicationhost.config
>   file that is located in the user's Documents folder.

So you need to add config key `/config:` and write the path to your config.